# How to convert rows of different sizes to columns with some recycled fields?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

My problem is the following:

I have a table on excel [3x5] with the following fields:

> ***a  1  2  3  4 ; b  5  6 ; c  7  8  9;***

And I want to transform it into:

---

> a  1; a  2; a  3; a  4; b  5; b  6; c  7; c  8; c  9;

---

How can I do this on excel or powerbi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If those data are in the rectangle A1:E3
In column G1 put `=IF(B1="","",$A1&" "&B1)` ; copy across to J, and copy down.
In column K put ; and copy down.
In column L1 put `=CONCATENATE(G1,K1,H1,K1,I1,K1,J1,K1)`
Now we have 1, but possibly 4, semicolons at the end; we want to get rid of any more than 1.
A working, but slightly cheeky, way is in N1 to put: `=SUBSTITUTE(L1,";;",";")` and copy to O and P, then down.

Then in R1 put `P1`.
But in R2 and copy down put: `=R1&P2`